# Pub quizzes in Bath, UK

Tags: entertainment, bath-england

I am currently travelling through UK and will spend several days in Bath. Being a big fan of pub quizzes I wish to experience them in their country of origin. My online queries didn't turn up much relevant information.

Is there a way to find out which Bath public houses host quizzes, and when?

Comment: If you find a good one, let me know... I'll be in Bath this weekend myself.

Comment: Most pub quiz's happen on week nights. Typically early in the week (they're a way to get people into the pub when it's quiet). You'll be hard pressed to find one at the weekend. They're often not advertised anywhere apart from maybe a board outside/inside the pub.

Comment: Also , dare I say it, bath may be a bit *posh* for pub quizzes....You're more likely to find a nice wine bar, in the centre at least.

Comment: Try a Wetherspoons. They tend to have quizzes midweek. I agree with @Liam though; you will probably just have to wander around until you find a board outside saying they have a quiz on.

Answer (score 5):

Pub quizzes can appear and disappear almost at will, but the following pubs have quizzes. These might change so ring them to make sure they are still running.  Remember no checking the answers on your mobile phone

Belushis   - Tuesday.   [Belushi's](http://www.belushis.com/bars/bath)

The cork. -  Sundays

Bath brewhouse. - Tuesday

The bear. -  every other Sunday

The swan. -  Mondays

You can find addresses and other pub listings here

[Beer In The Evening](http://www.beerintheevening.com/pubs/results.shtml?l=Bath+)

Comment: Oh. And if you see me. Buy me a pint

Answer (score 4):

I had lunch in [The Weston](http://www.westonbath.com/) yesterday, and saw that they advertise Quiz Night on Mondays starting at 8:30pm.